# STM32F722EZ Nucleo, ST-Link-v2-1, Openocd 0.10.0 open failed in "init" and "ocd_bouncer"

Tags: openocd

Windows7 64bit
With the Nucleo connected to USB port I was able to use ST-LINK Utility to download the hex file to the board successfully. But after execute the command:
 ..\bin\openocd.exe -f board\st_nucleo_f7.cfg
With st_nucleof7.cfg contains following lines:

source [find interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg]

transport select hla_swd

source [find target/stm32f7x.cfg]

reset_config srst_only

...and stlink-v2-1.cfg has:
interface hla
hla_layout stlink
hla_device_desc "ST-LINK/V2-1"
hla_vid_pid 0x0483 0x374b

...and Device Manager shows USB Device as "STLINK dongle" with Hardware lds Value as:
USB\VID_0483&PID_374B&REV_0100&MI_00
USB\VID_0483&PID_374B&MI_00

It seems all VID and PID are matched.
...but I got the following error. Could someone tell me what is wrong in my setup please?

GNU ARM Eclipse 64-bits Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0-00113-g0f83948 (2017-01-24-
18:48)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results mi
ght differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 2000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Error: open failed
in procedure 'init'
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Thank you Momin, but the error has nothing to do with my code so to speak. The issue is that I can't have the openocd to connect to the ST-LINK on my STM32 NucleoF722ZE evaluation board at all. This is why I presented the config file contain.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/openocd-fail-to-open-stm32-nucleo-board/

Evidently OpenOCD cannot connect to USB 3.0 port. I switched to another port and it worked!!! 
Why no one at OpenOCD instructs that it doesn't work with usb 3.0? I have spent a few days on this problem. 
I still don't know how to tell which port has 2.0 or 3.0 version looking at the Device Manager.

Comment: If you use STM32 dev boards for the non commercial purposes there is an interesting Segger option: https://www.segger.com/jlink-st-link.html. Much faster and IMHO better.